# Authentication: sessions, JWT, or something else?

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, jwt

I have a web server that serves a website to users. Through this website they can sign in using oauth, which I currently store in a session on the server. The session basically just tells me what user this is and if they are signed in or not (which is all I want from it).

I then have an API-server which is only used to query for information which might be protected (ie, only signed in users can see it). The API-server is only accessible through the main server, which just proxies everything through. The API-server has access to the same backing store which means it can read the sessions and process the requests requiring authentication checks. A nit to this approach is: since the session only lives in memory until saved, I need to save it every time a request is going to be proxied to the server to ensure the API-server has fresh data.

But thats not the true issue, the true issue is when a user visits say `/account`, I want to prefetch all the data they need and build the entire site on the server before sending them it (so they don't have to wait for the http-request and render the entire site again). This is problematic, because when the server tries to access an area only authenticated users can see, it gets denied. To work around this I would need to inject the session id in the request and re-work a lot of code which intuitively feels like the wrong approach. If I use JWT, I could perhaps create a "super user token" that the server would generate which would allow it access to any part of the authenticated area, but that also feels risky.

What do you guys think?

Some additional information that might be relevant:

- I'm using react and doing server side rendering
- I am using redux (which is the state I try to prefill)
- I am using Node

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a middle ware before controller in every secure route/endpoint
in this middle ware check your jwt token if token is valid then  call next middleware.

```
 router.route('/post')
.post(isAdmin,postCntr.addPost);



  function isAdmin (req, res, next) {
    var token = req.headers['authentication'] || req.body.token || req.params.token;
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    err: err,
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                });
            } else {

                next();
            }
        });

    } else {

        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }
}
```